# AS3: Graphics.lineStyle() -- Change ALPHA only?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

In the method `Graphics.lineStyle()` you pass the alpha as the third parameter. I don't want to change the thickness or color which are the first 2 parameters, so is there a way I can just change the alpha? or at least "get" the thickness and color so I can re-pass them so they wont change?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you subclassing something you don't have the source code to?  I ask because normally *you* set the alpha, thickness, etc. so you could cache those values

Comment: Yes I am extended a class that gets passed a Graphics object to draw on, that already has a lineStyle set. I am wanting to change the alpha only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to wrap the graphics object that you are passing around and add getters and setters for individual properties that are otherwise only available as parameters.

Pseudo-code:

```
public class CustomGraphics 
{
    // -- here is the wrapped graphics object
    protected var _graphics:Graphics;

    // -- unique properties for line style
    protected var _lineColor:uint;
    protected var _lineThickness:int;
    protected var _lineAlpha:Number;

    public function CustomGraphics( gfx:Graphics )
    {
          _graphics = gfx;
          _lineColor = 0;
          _lineThickness = 1;
          _lineAlpha = 1;

          draw();
    }

    public function set lineAlpha( value:Number ):void
    {
        if( _lineAlpha != value ) {
             _lineAlpha = value;
             // -- insert code to redraw or invalidate here
             draw();
        }
    }

    public function draw():void {
        _graphics.setLineStyle( _lineThickness, _lineColor, _lineAlpha );
    }
}
```